# WildFly 10 | Undertow | Create Wildfly LoginModule with access to RequestContext

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-10, requestcontext

i'm trying to create a login module for wildfly 10 with access to the request context. I must identify the request url. Also I have to analyse the GET parameters to check if a token is set.

How can I access to the request context and url informations in a "UsernamePasswordLoginModule" based class?

I have tried this

@Resource
WebServiceContext wsctx;

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your suggestion. But it doesn't work. The web filter doesn't call.

In the second step I have tried the following

```
try {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext
                .getContext(HttpServletRequest.class.getName());
    } catch (PolicyContextException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The result is that the method will probably terminate at this point (getContext) and the request is resubmitted. I don't know why.

Comment: I've found my issue. I've forgot to set the dependency "javax.servlet.api" in my module.xml

Answer (score 0):

You should implement some preprocessor for saving request params to some ThreadLocal variable ( For example, you can do it in Web filter) . Then in your login module you will be able to read this params from ThreadLocal one.